# Running android program produces error log as fatal exception in main

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run my android applicatioin.I am using eclipse with android 4.4.2 sdk.When i try to run this in emulator many errors comming in logcat such as fatal exception in main.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.j;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView t;
Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                   t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                   b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        t.setText(String.valueOf("button Pressed"));

                    }
                });
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.j.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

This is my fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.j.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

error log as

```
06-18 02:15:19.740: D/dalvikvm(889): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-18 02:15:22.650: D/AndroidRuntime(889): Shutting down VM
06-18 02:15:22.650: W/dalvikvm(889): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aa0ba8)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Process: com.example.j, PID: 889
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.j/com.example.j.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.example.j.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-18 02:15:22.690: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to this

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Comment: @johnson can you post full error log in question ??

Comment: i have added the log file

Comment: @johnson what is line number `25` in `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: @johnson see my update answer i think this is solve your problem see.